# What are all of the possible Class Names in QTP or where can I find them?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm using QTP 11 and I could use a handy reference for all of the possible values for "Class Name". I'm not trying to manipulate this information. I just need a reference. 
For example I know that I can access any input element using "WebEdit()" but what do I use for, say, a table cell.

I want a list I can refer to, not steps for finding the type of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three options come to mind immediately:**

**Option A. The handiest way to find the names probably is to look into the dialog Tools/Object Identification.**

There, in the "Test Object classes" listview, you see all test object class names for the environment selected under "Environment" that QTP knows of.

**Option B. If in the dialog from A. you push the "Generate script" button**, creating a script. **Use a grep facility** (or TextPad, for that matter) **to extract all lines containing the text "Object identification configuration for" from that script. This results in a text which after some cleanup is these lists**:

User-defined (?):

```
"abtobjectgraphicswidget"
"cwarrowbutton"
"cwcheckbutton"
"cwlabel"
"cwpushbutton"
"cwradiobutton"
"cwtext"
"cwtext_multi"
"ewflowediconlist"
"ewiconarea"
"ewiconlist"
"ewicontree"
"ewpmnotebook"
"ewspinbutton"
"ewtablelist"
"ewtabletree"
"ewwinnotebook"
"gxcombobox"
"gxedit"
"gxlistbox"
"listview20wndclass"
"listviewwndclass"
"msvb_lib_toolbar"
"richedit"
"seccustomtoolbar"
"secmenubar"
"sectabctrl"
"sectabwnd"
"sectreectrl"
"sectreeview"
"stgrid"
"sysdatetimepick32"
"sysmonthcal32"
"textedit"
"treeview20wndclass"
"treeviewwndclass"
```

Standard (?):

```
"activex"
"acxbutton"
"acxcalendar"
"acxcheckbox"
"acxcombobox"
"acxedit"
"acxradiobutton"
"acxtable"
"javaapplet"
"javabutton"
"javacalendar"
"javacheckbox"
"javadialog"
"javaedit"
"javaexpandbar"
"javainternalframe"
"javalink"
"javalist"
"javamenu"
"javaobject"
"javaradiobutton"
"javaslider"
"javaspin"
"javastatictext"
"javatab"
"javatable"
"javatoolbar"
"javatree"
"javawindow"
"dialog"
"static"
"winbutton"
"wincalendar"
"wincheckbox"
"wincombobox"
"window"
"winedit"
"wineditor"
"winlist"
"winlistview"
"winmenu"
"winobject"
"winradiobutton"
"winradiogroup"
"winscrollbar"
"winspin"
"winstatusbar"
"wintab"
"wintable"
"wintoolbar"
"wintreeview"
"browser"
"frame"
"image"
"link"
"page"
"viewlink"
"webarea"
"webbutton"
"webcheckbox"
"webedit"
"webelement"
"webfile"
"weblist"
"webradiogroup"
"webtable"
```

Note 1: the user-defined objects are probably add-on specific, or otherwise registered in a special way in QTP.
Note 2: this is just a sample of what you might get on your machine. For example, I don´t have the Delphi add-on active, so all the Delphi control´s test object class names are missing. If you want me to activate all add-ons, and re-create this list, I´ll give you my bank account first ;)

**Option C. In the online help, from the contents, try navigating to the "HP QuickTest Professional Object Model Reference". It contains chapters per environment, and most of them consist of "X Object" chapters**, i.e. there is a "WebButton Object" chapter under "Web".

**Option D. See Rich's answer** :-O

Answer (score 1):

Since `micclass` is the same thing as the `Class Name` property (other than programming placement), the class names of the objects that you are trying to apply to micclass can be utilized. To find the class names of all objects used in the QTP environment, you can use the `Mercury.ObjectRepositoryUtil` to iterate through the objects and collect what's necessary for the micclass.

More details on that -> [Here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/QTP-Get-Object-Class-from-the-Object-name-in-the-Repository/td-p/5240696#.U1WF5vldU2s) and [Here](http://www.learnqtp.com/forums/Thread-How-to-use-Mercury-ObjectRepositoryUtil-to-load-repositories-dynamically)

Comment: Thank you, Rich, but I don't think that is quite what I'm looking for. Unless I just misunderstood your answer. I've rephrased my question and added some more detail.

Comment: Well, there is a problem with that because objects can be moved in and out of preconfigured, local or remote object repositories, they can vary on class names. So that's why there is no "list of class names" available and why I gave you a tool to find the objects class names.  Here's some more information on ORs. Http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/qtp-tutorial-22-using-qtp-object-repositories/

Comment: On the other hand, the QTP dox clearly list all test object names that QTP supports out of the box (and via add-ons). So the real answer could be "rtfm"

Comment: @TheBlastOne I did 'rtfm' but admittedly not thoroughly. I tried to do a search for the object names an couldn't find it. I only have access to the program for about 2 1/2 hours a day so my time is limited. What section in the docs has the list?

Comment: See my own answer. Sigh ;)

Comment: @TheBlastOne Nice list. Is this for 11? What version? I want the OP to be happy with whatever answer regardless of the outcome. And, if you really want to sort through a list every time, go for it. or... you can just type in `Object.GetTOProperty("micClass")` and get the class name for any object directly. ...Even if possibly incompatible and incomplete lists are still preferred with your approach. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, it´s not my approach. It´s just my answer to what the OP is asking. List is from 11, release doesn't matter.
I know, however, occasions where you want f.e. in library code call registerUserFunc for a rather generic function for all test object classes one uses. QTP does not really offer anything like that. Querying the OR is incomplete as it does not cover classes one adresses only by DP descriptions. In such cases, a hardcoded array of names and iterating over that array (or externing the array into a parameter file) appears like the only viable solution. So I see OP has a point.